# Using python itertools groupby

Tags: python

I have an array that i'd like to apply the groupby recipe described here to:
https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/itertools.html#examples

Here's the code I have...

```
from operator import itemgetter, attrgetter, methodcaller
from itertools import groupby


myArray = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89]


for k, g in groupby(myArray, lambda (i,x):i-x):
    c = map(itemgetter(1), g)
    print(c)
```

Unfortunately this is resulting in the following error in the blender console:

```
location: <unknown location>:-1
Error:   File "/home/anon/Desktop/objects/dev_space.blend/Text", line 666
for k, g in groupby(enumerate(myArray), lambda (i,x):i-x):
```

What am I missing? I'm assuming Blender ought to support this recipe out-of-the-box(tm)

Comment: I found the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35181413/find-runs-of-consecutive-numbers-using-groupby-in-python

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html?highlight=groupby#itertools.groupby  - recent versions of Blender are not Python 2.6 compatible.

Comment: @zeffii thanks, where does Blender record this kind of info.

Comment: the _python console_ view will show the python version